# WSO2 IOTS: How to create new Project from scratch

Tags: wso2

Sorry for my bad English. I currently work hard on testing WSO2 IOTS server, but I can't find the way to create any things new from scratch.

I create sample device with command: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local`, modify code and deploy it with command: `mvn clean install -f device-deployer.xml`.

I known WSO2 IOTS is a collection of other component. In situation, I must create one large Project and create small component project in this, right? Please explan me how?

Comment: It will be easy to help if you specifically mention what you want to achieve. Are you searching for information on how a new device type plugin can be written and plugged into IoT Server?

Comment: Yes, but each component have it's document. I don't known how it work together, I look into pom.xml file, I try create same project with inteliJ IDE and maven but it not work, sorry I'm new to WSO2 platform. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get an idea by following the guide [1]. This mainly walks-through using an example about the components and how /why they are used in IoT Server.

For you to get things going you can create your own device type using the maven archetype [2]. This maven archetype will give you a skeleton device which you can further extend as you need. It will be a good starting point since basic wiring for a device plugin is already been done.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Device+Manufacturer+Guide

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Creating+a+New+Device+Type